# Angular file upload to Teamwork API

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my issue...

I'm trying to upload a file via Angular 6 to Teamwork API
https://developer.teamwork.com/projects/file-uploading/upload-a-file
however no matter what file I try to upload I always get the error message
"the form field 'file' did not contain a valid file"

I've tried sending without content-type, content-type: undefined etc
I've tried adding the file object into formdata

Here is some code:

--- template file ---

```
<input type="file" [id]="question.id" class="form-control" (change)="onUpload($event)">
<button class="btn btn-update"><i class="icon-success file-continue" (click)="onUpdate($event)"></i></button>
```

--- component ---

```
onUpload(event: any) {
  this.uploadObject = event.target.files[0];
  this.uploadName = event.target.files[0].name;
}
onUpdate(event: any) {
  this.twApiService.uploadFile(this.uploadObject).subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

--- service ---

```
uploadFile(uploadObject: any) {
  const url = 'https://[hidden].teamwork.com/pendingfiles.json';
  const fileObject = { file: uploadObject };
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'BASIC ' + window.btoa(this.key + ':xxx')});
  return this.http.post(url, fileObject, {headers});
}
```

I tried many versions of this code with everything I found across the internet in the past 3 days and nothing worked. I always get this error:
"the form field 'file' did not contain a valid file"

Can someone give my some instructions how to fix this or at least to try something different?

Regards, Ivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the teamwork API and its weird because them expect a request body application/json (when usually file upload is handling via formdata request)

So try this first and check in network tab that it is application/json request:

```
uploadFile(uploadObject: any) {
  const url = 'https://[hidden].teamwork.com/pendingfiles.json';
  const fileObject = { file: uploadObject };
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'BASIC ' + window.btoa(this.key + ':xxx')});
  return this.http.post(url, fileObject, {headers});
}
```

If that not work try formData way
Here is important that not set manually formData type because it automatically recognise it.

```
uploadFile(uploadObject: any) {
  const url = 'https://[hidden].teamwork.com/pendingfiles.json';
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', uploadobject);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'BASIC ' + window.btoa(this.key + ':xxx')});
  return this.http.post(url, formData, {headers});
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks anthony, that actually worked - formData way. I already tried this but inside the component and then sending it to the service. However now I tried this inside the service exactly how you showed and it actually worked! Thank you very much.